# How to check where the Apache2 hangs?

Tags: apache2

My Apache2 hangs. I can't get any response from it.

I tried to run `wget localhost`

it just hangs like this:

```
--2012-03-12 06:36:40--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

How can I get more debug information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `netstat -nt` to see what connections there are to port 80 from 127.0.0.1.

You can use `fuser -n tcp 80,127.0.0.1,<port-number>` to look for the PID of the Apache process which has port 80 TCP connection from 127.0.0.1 from the given .

Then do an `strace -p <pid>` on that process to see what it's doing at the system call level.

You can take out the pid-finding steps if you restart Apache in single-process mode (provided that the hang still reproduces!) If that were the case I would just run that Apache under `strace` and capture the trace.

Based on that I would decide what to do next. Is it hanging in a syscall, not hanging in a syscall, ... which syscall. Last resorts would be getting a debugging build and `gdb`-ing it.

Apache debugging guide: http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html

Comment: Downvoted because `fuser -n ...` gives me `Unknown option: n`

Comment: @LincolnBergeson The `-n <namespace>` is indeed specific to a version of `fuser` commonly found in Linux distributions. The FreeBSD `fuser` doesn't have this option. In Solaris, the `-n` option to `fuser` means "list only processes that have non-blocking mandatory locks on a file".

Comment: @Kaz Tried to remove the downvote but SO locked it. I'm on a Mac. Thanks for the clarification :-)

Comment: @LincolnBergeson I just shut down my MacOS VM one minute ago to try it. http://superuser.com/questions/225229/what-to-you-use-as-a-fuser-v-n-tcp-alternative-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

Try `tail -f /var/log/apache/error_log`.

Your path to the `error_log` may be different. To search for it, try `find / -name error_log`. If you're not logged in as `root` then you may see a bunch of "permission denied". In that case you can hide the error messages with `find / -name error_log 2>/dev/null` or try to guess the location with `find /var/log/ -name error_log`.